# complete converter and tasks doesn't exists in namespace

Tags: c#, wpf

so i trying to create the datagrid out from msdn 
but i getting an error and i am not sure why as i copy pastet the whole thing  directly from msdn

i getting the error on the

```
<local:CompleteConverter x:Key="completeConverter" />
    <local:Tasks x:Key="tasks" />
```

that says

> it doesn't exists in clr-namespace:DGGroupSortFilterExample

[i be using that one in the Example section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_4)

CS

```
namespace DGGroupSortFilterExample
{
 public class CompleteConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        // This converter changes the value of a Tasks Complete status from true/false to a string value of
        // "Complete"/"Active" for use in the row group header.
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool complete = (bool)value;
            if (complete)
                return "Complete";
            else
                return "Active";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string strComplete = (string)value;
            if (strComplete == "Complete")
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

public class Task : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
    {
        // The Task class implements INotifyPropertyChanged and IEditableObject 
        // so that the datagrid can properly respond to changes to the 
        // data collection and edits made in the DataGrid.

        // Private task data.
        private string m_ProjectName = string.Empty;
        private string m_TaskName = string.Empty;
        private DateTime m_DueDate = DateTime.Now;
        private bool m_Complete = false;

        // Data for undoing canceled edits.
        private Task temp_Task = null;
        private bool m_Editing = false;

        // Public properties. 
        public string ProjectName
        {
            get { return this.m_ProjectName; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.m_ProjectName)
                {
                    this.m_ProjectName = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("ProjectName");
                }
            }
        }
      public class Tasks : ObservableCollection<Task>
    {
        // Creating the Tasks collection in this way enables data binding from XAML.
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="DGGroupSortFilterExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DGGroupSortFilterExample"
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        Title="Group, Sort, and Filter Example" Height="575" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CompleteConverter x:Key="completeConverter" />
        <local:Tasks x:Key="tasks" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsTasks" Source="{StaticResource tasks}" 
                              Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <!-- Requires 'xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"' declaration. -->
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="ProjectName"/>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Complete" />
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="DueDate" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ProjectName"/>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Complete"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsTasks}}"
                  CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="#FF112255" BorderBrush="#FF002255" Foreground="#FFEEEEEE" BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <DockPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                                </DockPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <Expander.Content>
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Expander.Content>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
                <!-- Style for groups under the top level. -->
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel Background="LightBlue">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Converter={StaticResource completeConverter}}" Foreground="Blue" Margin="30,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text=" Filter completed items " VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbCompleteFilter" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Checked="CompleteFilter_Changed" Unchecked="CompleteFilter_Changed" />
            <Button Content="Remove Groups" Margin="10,2,2,2" Click="UngroupButton_Click" />
            <Button Content="Group by Project/Status" Margin="2" Click="GroupButton_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: And *have* you included the `CompleteConverter` class from the sample? Is it in the `DGGroupSortFilterExample` namespace?

Comment: yes but should it be maded is an external class

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand that comment at all.

Comment: please add a WPF / SL tag to the question, mate.

Comment: @jon skeet you know like right click on your csproj >add>class 
thats what i call an external class

Comment: Remove the xml comments from your XAML <!-- -->. The designer hates those.

Comment: That's just "a class in your project". Not sure why it would be internal...

Comment: Also, maybe the order in which XAML is parsed is reversed.. try swapping the order between 'cvsTasks' and 'tasks'

Comment: removed the comments and that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try compiling.. the designer is made aware of new classes only after compilation. if after compilation this isn't resolved- post your entire XAML document, and c# code for that class. Make sure the namespace and using statements are visible.

Comment: please post the complete XAML document as well.

Comment: also tell me, are the converter and XAML document in the same VS project? note that the "local" xmlns is an autogenerated xmlns for the root namespace of the project where the XAML document resides. so another reason for the designer to not locate the converter, is that the local xmlns indeed does not contain the converter, since it is in another project.

Comment: yes it is  
i had just copy pastet it directly from msdn into the xaml and in the CS as it is on their documentation